# Makefile prerequisites before rules

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to force a specific condition before the rules are evaluated?

Ex:

```
FOOPATH = $(shell which foo)
ifndef $(FOOPATH)
    echo "Error: foo is not avaliable."
    # abort make
endif
```

PS: I'm not looking for a solution to add prerequisites do every rule that depends on foo (because the entire Makefile should depend on foo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>FOOPATH = $(shell which foo)</strike>

```
ifeq ($(FOOPATH),)
$(error foo is not available)
endif
```

(Note that `FOOPATH` is defined, even if it is empty.)

**EDIT: Correction--** I was wrong about `ifndef`; it returns `true` if the variable is defined but has an empty value. **But** it won't work as written because of the way `FOOPATH` is assigned a value:

```
FOOPATH = $(shell which foo)
```

The value of `FOOPATH` is literally "$(shell which foo)", so the `ifndef` will never evaluate as true, and you'll never see the error. The solution is to use a [simply expanded variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors):

```
FOOPATH := $(shell which foo)   # <-- note the colon
```

Also, `ifndef` should be applied to a variable *name*, not its *value* (e.g. `FOOPATH` not `$(FOOPATH)`).

```
ifndef FOOPATH
$(error foo is not available)
endif
```

Comment: according to [this page](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html) `ifdef` evaluetes to true when the var "has a non-empty value"

Comment: You are right about `ifndef`, but the value of `$(FOOPATH)` when assigned with `=` is the result of `$(shell which foo)`, I tested

Comment: If you prefer to add the final solution to your answer, I won't mind to delete my answer

Comment: @RSFalcon7: I tested it too, with `ifndef` and `value`. How did you test it?

Comment: FOOPATH = $(shell which ls 2>/dev/null) ;
$(warning FOOPATH value is $(FOOPATH)) ;

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Your test expands the variable; you're doing it wrong.

Comment: In this case, how do you propose the test?

Comment: `FOOPATH = $(shell which ls 2>/dev/null); $(info $(value FOOPATH))` If I'm right, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For further information, this is my final solution, with a lot a help from @Beta

```
FOOPATH = $(shell which ls 2>/dev/null)

ifeq ($(FOOPATH),)
$(error foo is not avaliable)
else
$(warning foo is avaliable in $(FOOPATH))
endif

all:
    @echo "rule all executed"
```